# Summation of a series given n as number of terms (recursion)

Tags: java, function, recursion

I need to make a recursive function that calculates the sum of a series with the formula:

(3x-1)/2(x+1) /* x increases per cycle and x starts at 1*/

For example: if you inputted 2, the answer must be 1.3333 from [(2/4)+(5/6)]

I already made a code for the function that performs the operation, but it outputs 0.0 for values 0 - 2 and 1.0 for everything greater than 2.

```
public double summation(int intN){
    if(intN == 0)
        return dbSum;
    else {
        dbSum = ((3*intX)-1)/(2*(intX+1));
        intX++;
    }
    return (summation(intN - 1));
}
```

I desperately need help for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you intending to increment `dbSum` by that amount? If so, you might want to use `+=` (increment), rather than just using `=` (assign).

Comment: yes I am. I just tried your suggestion and it still gave the same output as earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are intending to increment `dbSum`, you should use the increment operator:

```
dbSum += ((3*intX)-1)/(2*(intX+1));
      ^ Here
```

Additionally, you are actually doing integer division: `(2/4)+(5/6) == 0 + 0 == 0`, not `1.333...`, even if you are assigning it to a `double`. You need to force at least one of the numerator and denominator to be a double:

```
dbSum += ((3.0*intX)-1)/(2.0*(intX+1));
```

---

Note that you have an initialization issue, as well as a thread-safety issue in this code, because you're using a member variable to hold the result: you need to make sure that `dbSum == 0` initially, and that no other thread calls the method at the same time. It would be much safer if you didn't use a member variable:

```
public double summation(int intN){
  if(intN == 0)
    return dbSum;
  else {
    return ((3.0*intX)-1)/(2.0*(intX+1)) + summation(intN - 1);
  }
}
```

(You can write it tail recursively too; although that doesn't really help you in Java). A `for` loop would be a better strategy overall, but I guess that this is an exercise in recursion.

Comment: dbSum is indeed initialized as 0 in the class before the summation function. I tried the else statement that you provided, but there is no change whatsoever in the results.

Comment: oh the sum did change. but instead of 1.3333 it showed 0.5

Comment: @schwall you need to reset the value to zero every time you call the method: currently, if you call the method 3 times for the same input, you would get a different result (provided you fix the integer division and `intN > 0`).

Comment: thanks. I forgot to update since I have slow internet here in PH but it finally worked.